calling existing AWS Lambda functions using the API Gateway URL directly with Swift?
I had a very basic Flask server while developing my apis locally and now it's time to port them over to AWS Lambda which I've done so using serverless to get everything deployed through configuration files without any problems.
Is this the only route I can go? https://docs.amplify.aws/swift/build-a-backend/auth/use-existing-cognito-resources/#use-auth-resources-without-an-amplify-backend ?
Is it possible to not rely on 3rd party libraries and directly call the API Gateway url in Swift, somehow? Something like this:
class APIGatewayManager {
    static let shared = APIGatewayManager()
    
    private let baseURL: String
    
    private init() {
        self.baseURL = "https://abc123def.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/dev"
    }
    
    func makeAPICall<T: Codable>(path: String, method: String, body: [String: Any]? = nil) async throws -> T {
        guard let url = URL(string: baseURL + path) else {
            throw APIError.invalidURL
        }
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = method
        
        if let body = body {
            request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body)
            request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }
        
        let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
        
        guard let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
              (200...299).contains(httpResponse.statusCode) else {
            throw APIError.invalidResponse
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        return try decoder.decode(T.self, from: data)
    }
}

enum APIError: Error {
    case invalidURL
    case invalidResponse
    case decodingError
}

class ProfilesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchProfiles() async {
        do {
            let profiles: [DecodableProfile] = try await APIGatewayManager.shared.makeAPICall(path: "/profiles", method: "GET")
            self.profiles = profiles.map { $0.toProfile() }
            self.showToastMessage("Fetched profiles successfully", isSuccess: true)
        } catch {
            self.showToastMessage("Error fetching profiles: \(error.localizedDescription)", isSuccess: false)
        }
    }
    
    @MainActor
    func updateProfile(_ profile: Profile) async {
        do {
            let updatedProfile: DecodableProfile = try await APIGatewayManager.shared.makeAPICall(
                path: "/profiles/\(profile.id)",
                method: "PUT",
                body: profile.toDecodableProfile().dictionary
            )
            if let index = self.profiles.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == updatedProfile.id }) {
                self.profiles[index] = updatedProfile.toProfile()
            }
            self.showToastMessage("Profile updated successfully", isSuccess: true)
        } catch {
            self.showToastMessage("Error updating profile: \(error.localizedDescription)", isSuccess: false)
        }
    }
}

extension Encodable {
    var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
        guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
        return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)) as? [String: Any]
    }
}

Tried setting up Amplify to work with existing Lambda S3 service through API Gateway/Serverless but got lost very quickly.
